# Why C# WMI ManagementObject.InvokeCommand works and SetProperty with Put doesn't

Tags: c#, wmi

Is there a reason why only 1 of the two examples below work when trying to set Service StartMode ?

```
ManagementObjectCollection services = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query).Get();

foreach (ManagementObject service in services)
{
    // WORKS
    service.InvokeMethod("ChangeStartMode", new object[] { ServiceStartMode.Manual });
    // DOESN'T WORK
    service.SetPropertyValue("StartMode", ServiceStartMode.Manual);
    service.Put();
}
```

- Running with Admin
- SetPropertyValue doesn't give an error and displays updated value if printed, but it's never updated in WMI itself. Windows services console shows correct value only when InvokeMethod is used.

Connect Options:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\cimv2", new ConnectionOptions
{
    Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
    Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Connect,
    EnablePrivileges = true
});
```

Comment: maybe the property does not have a setter?

Comment: it has - SetPropertyValue works as expected, but .Put() doesn't do anything except returning correct path (equals service.Path.Path).

Comment: @AistisRemeika [StartMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service) is read-only. `SetPropertyValue` doesn't execute anything. Any changes to the *local* object will be applied when `Put()` is called. `ManagementObject` isn't the actual service, it's a DTO returned by the OS which you can use to modify properties and apply changes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you update local object using SetPropretyValue and then propogate with Put. e.g. You can play around with Win32_UserAccount and set Disabled. I was confused, because Put did not throw any exception and returned correct path. See NicoRiff answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the vast majority of `Win32_Service` properties are read-only and are only meant to be modified through the methods that the class expose. You can see that in the definition of the class

> StartMode - String
>            Qualifiers: CIMTYPE, Description, Override, **read**, ValueMap, Values

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. So I guess the only problem is that we don't get any exception when we are trying to update read-only properties.